# Offline Single Page Application, browser is trying to download manifest file from current loaded url upon page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application, offline-caching

I am working on single page application. The app uses application cache for offline experience. I have setup manifest file and placed in public folder. Whenever app is loaded, the manifest file is downloaded from 
`http://example.com:9001/td.manifest`.

In my app, I have two urls

1. `http://example.com:9001/`
2. `http://example.com:9001/user/`

Upon clicking user tab, browser is navigated to `http://example.com:9001/user/` (via client side routing). At this point,
if user refreshes page, manifest file will be looked into `http://example.com:9001/user/td.manifest` location. When manifest file is not found then all the resources will downloaded again. How do I configure my app or manifest file, that it has to look always for manifest file in the location `http://example.com:9001/td.manifest`, irrespective the location from where refresh is triggered ?

These are console logs when I refresh page, also request for manifest is going as 
`http://example.com:9001/null`

`Creating Application Cache with manifest http://example.com:9001/user/td.manifest
user:1 Application Cache Checking event
user:1 Application Cache Error event: Failed to parse manifest http://example.com:9000/user/td.manifest`

Here is my html fragment which uses td.manifest

[image: Image shows adding td.manifest file]

Comment: Can you please add the html5 fragement that utilizes the manifest. Do you use push state to maintain client side URL navigation? Can you please add the response headers of your manifest files by looking into your debuggers network console (don't forget to remove private data like basic auth passwords or session IDs)?

Comment: added logs and image of html. No I am not using push state.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, inside `index.html`, added `<html manifest="http://example.com:9001/td.manifest">`